# How to delete rows in MySQL which have same value for a column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have something like this:

```
col1 col2 col3
A      B   C
A      B   C
```

I want only one row to remain out of these and other to be deleted. What query to implement?

Comment: easy - `DELETE TOP(1) FROM table`

Comment: @Uriel_SVK he want's to delete all but the first.

Comment: Is there a unique key on these rows?

Comment: This would have been much easy if there was a primary key http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b0ae9c/1

Comment: @Taemyr no he wants `only one row to remain out of these and other to be deleted` so my answer does exactly what he asks for.

Comment: @Uriel_SVK Fair enough, he doesn't specify exactly which row he wants to keep.  Your SQL still only deletes a single entry, and he wants all but one to be deleted.

Comment: A primary key should be a prerequisite of an RDBMs table. As such, we can reject the premise of the question

Comment: no there is no primary key

Comment: provide unique key to some column will delete your repeted entries

Comment: @Taemyr hmmm ... `set @test = null;  
select count(col1)-1 from items into @test;  
PREPARE STMT FROM 'delete from items limit ?';  
EXECUTE STMT USING @test;# ` this is fun :D Still no idea what exactly he needs though... :/

Comment: @user3529351 can you pls add more info to your question? Are all the data A, B, C? You need only one row from table, or one of every duplicity? What have you tried and why did it not work. Show some effort man...

Comment: @Strawberry I think MySql allows tables with no primary key.

Comment: @Taemyr That's not really the point. Relational tables require PKs, regardless of what the specific flavour of SQL does or doesn't allow!

Comment: @Strawberry Since OP talks about a spesific flavor of SQL I think that this specific flavor is more important than the mathematical ideal.

Comment: @Taemyr I absolutely disagree. Relational tables require PRIMARY KEYs. If you're not going to bother with the PK, don't bother with the RDBMS!

Comment: @Strawberry cstheory is [over there](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/), here I think we have to relate to the system in the way they are designed.  We might not like the fact that a system allows for no PK, but that is the system that is given. - Also  this discussion is growing off topic so I will not write further replies.

Answer (score 2):

If you want **both duplicates** to be removed, try this:

```
DELETE m.*
FROM mytable m
INNER JOIN
  (SELECT col1,
    col2,
    col3,
    COUNT(*)
  FROM mytable
  GROUP BY col1,
    col2,
    col3
  HAVING COUNT(*)>1
  ) t
ON m.col1 =t.col1
AND m.col2=t.col2
AND m.col3=t.col3
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/95906e/13)

**EDIT**

As you have edited your question and want **one out of two duplicate rows** to remain, you can easily achieve this with the following line:

```
  ALTER IGNORE TABLE mytable ADD UNIQUE INDEX idx_yourindexname (col1, col2, col3);
```

This will remove all of your duplicate rows, so that only unique ones are kept. The IGNORE keyword in compulsory because you already have data disobeying the INDEX in your table. Movereover, this will not allow for the duplicate insertions in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You can try;

```
delete from table where col1 = 'A' and col2 = 'B' and col3 = 'C' limit 1;
```

You could use a record count, etc.  in the limit clause to delete more records.